# NodeJS: cut out images using coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, imagemagick, tesseract

I have an image with an integer value, i can detect the text in the image using tesseract and a node module imagemagick. 
The Problem is the image size:

[image]

however cuting the image out like this:

[image: image within the detection works]

solved the problem.

So I want to cut the image out using node some thing lik this:

```
var image = cutOut(x1, y1, x2, y2, callback)
```

Any Ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ImageMagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) package that you've mentioned:

```
im.crop({
  srcPath: path,
  dstPath: 'cropped.jpg',
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  quality: 1,
  gravity: "North"
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  // foo
});
```

More info: https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick#cropoptions-callback